# How to divide list according to the pattern?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, argument-patterns

There is a list of lists:

```
{{0,0,0}, {0,0,1}, {0,1,0}, {0,1,1}, {1,0,0}, {1,0,1}, {1,1,0}, {1,1,1}}
```

I need to regrup it's elements according to a pattern: "if the first and the third elements are the same, make a partition". So I need to get following result:

```
{{{0,0,0},{0,1,0}}, {{0,0,1},{0,1,1}}, {{1,0,0},{1,1,0}}, {{1,0,1},{1,1,1}}}
```

How can I do it in Mathematica?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
GatherBy[list, #[[{1, 3}]] &]
```

> {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}},
>   {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}},
>    {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}},
>    {{1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}}

Alternatively,

```
Gather[list, #[[{1, 3}]] == #2[[{1, 3}]] &]
```

> same result

or

```
Values @ GroupBy[list, #[[{1, 3}]] &]
```

> same result

Answer (score 2):

You can also select the ones with identical first and third entries, then use complement to get the rest:

```
list = {{0,0,0}, {0,0,1}, {0,1,0}, {0,1,1}, {1,0,0}, {1,0,1}, {1,1,0}, {1,1,1}};

{sel = Select[list, #[[1]] == #[[3]] &], Complement[list, sel]}
{{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, 
 {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}}
```